# Excel - IF and SEARCH functions

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, excel-formula

Let's say I have 6 cells containing these words respectively:

1. RICE CAKE         (T)
2. COOKING OIL       (T)
3. SUGAR ROLL        (T)
4. CENTURY EGGS      (T)
5. SALTED EGGS       (T)
6. LARGE EGGS        (E)

I used this formula but it did not work fully. `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"*oil*","salted*","*sugar*","*rice*","*century*"},A1)),"T",FALSE)`

- What should I add in the formula to make sure that cell 6 would return value of "E"?
- RICE, OIL, SUGAR, CENTURY, SALTED should return a value of "T" (as shown in my formula)
- EGGS alone should return a value of "E" (like in cell number 6 WITHOUT coinciding with cell number 4 and 5 which contains eggs as well but they should be T)

How do I use any formula to return the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version

`=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(H222,"*"&{"Rice","Oil","sugar","Century","Salted"}&"*")),"T",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("eggs",H222)),"E",""))`

Add "Quail" to the first part if required

Edit: I didn't see your edit - I think that's a version I suggested elsewhere (with COUNT). That should work, what problem did you get? You don't need the "wildcards" with SEARCH (you do with COUNTIF) so that could be like this

`=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"oil","salted","sugar","rice","century"},A1)),"T",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("eggs",A1)),"E",""))`

Comment: wow thank you very much! how do you know the cell I am gonna use is H222? :O

Comment: oh i was wondering how come! anyways thank you very much barry :) glad for your help! much appreciated!

Comment: + 1 Another nice formula Barry :)